# Object not received correctly by Angular directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, asp.net-web-api2

I have a person object defined (loaded from the backend), that looks like this:

```
{
    "PersonId":"19894711-2eb9-4edf-92c6-85de2b33d1bb",
    "Firstname":"Jacky",
    "Lastname":"Chan",
    "DateOfBirth":"1963-09-18T00:00:00",
    "CreateDate":"2015-12-11T09:15:49.403",
    "ModifyDate":"2015-12-11T09:15:49.403"
}
```

It's displayed correctly using this HTML code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Firstname</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" ng-model="person.Firstname" class="form-control"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Lastname</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" ng-model="person.Lastname" class="form-control"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

But, if I pass that very same object to a directive:

```
<address-displayer-directive person="person"></address-displayer-directive>
```

It doesn't work.

This is the code of the directive:

```
myApp.directive("addressDisplayerDirective", [
    "addressService",
    function (
        addressService) {
        return {
            scope: {
                person: "="
            },
            restrict: "E",
            templateUrl: "/Templates/Directives/addressDisplayerDirective.html",
            controller: [
                "$scope",
                function ($scope) {
                    console.log($scope.person);

                    $scope.addresses = addressService.GetForPerson($scope.person.Id);
                }],
            link: function ($scope, $elem, $attrs) {
                console.log($attrs.person);
            }
        };
    }]);
```

That `console.log` at the link block, displays `"person"` (as a string, not an object).

The `console.log` at the controller block, displays `undefined`.

I tried simulating it with a [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/z4IlIMpnknWHfx3fxxUE?p=preview), but there it works.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this just a typo that you have `person="person"` in your *closing* HTML tag? If so, this is definitely wrong

Comment: Yep, copy paste error trying to set up my question. That's not how it really is...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing the log when initially only (thus getting undefined). You need to watch when the object is populated then perform the service call.

```
    controller: [
            "$scope",
            function ($scope) {
                console.log($scope.person);
                $scope.$watch(function(){
                    return $scope.person;
                }, function(){
                    if($scope.person && $scope.person.PersonId){
                        $scope.addresses = addressService.GetForPerson($scope.person.Id);
                    }
                });                    
            }],
```

Comment: That works! The object being passed on (person) is a _promise_ object, asynchronously loaded, so makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but doing this, you only pass the string "person" to your directive.

Try this :

```
<address-displayer-directive person="{{person}}"></address-displayer-directive>
```

Comment: That would be required if `person: '@'` would have been defined in the directive's scope declaration. (to allow for expression evaluation)